# How to construct redirect URL for foursquare iOS app

Tags: ios, foursquare

I'm developing an iPhone app using foursquare api. It has a Venue checkin screen with 'Check-IN' button and when the user clicks the button the foursquare authentication page will open up. The problem is that how do I get back to the Venue Checking page after successful authentication and checkin at foursquare.

I guess I have to use REDIRECT_URL judiciously for iphone app - but have very little clue how to do it.

Any suggestion will be very helpful.

Thanking you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should open up the foursquare auth flow in an embedded web-view. See https://github.com/anoopr/core-data-talk/blob/master/example/Classes/FoursquareAuthViewController.m for some sample code